# WCF WebService caused client to throw timeout exception (not on all clients)

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a WebService using WCF (written in C#) and I have this weird problem. In places where internet is a little bit slow, client keep getting timeout (instead of immediate disconnection) even though WCF has returned a value.

Here is my wait function (WCF)

```
public byte[] WaitForUpdate()
{
    StartWaitUpdate();  //maximum wait time is 230 seconds
    ...
    ...
    ...
    switch (OperationContext.Current.Channel.State)
    {
        case CommunicationState.Closed:
        case CommunicationState.Closing:
        case CommunicationState.Faulted:
            CommonLog.AddToLog(1, E_LogType.Error, "Channel state is no longer valid.");
            return null;
    }

    if ((updatedRecs == null) || (updatedRecs.Count == 0))
    {
        CommonLog.AddToLog(1, E_LogType.Information, "DEBUG - Return NULL.");
        return null;
    }

    CommonLog.AddToLog(1, E_LogType.Information, "DEBUG - Return Recs.");
    byte[] retBytes = SerializeBytes(updatedRecs);
    CommonLog.AddToLog(1, E_LogType.Information, "DEBUG - Byte Serialized.");
    return retBytes;
}
```

But in client, I keep getting this exception:

```
System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:05:59.9897301. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> 
System.TimeoutException: The HTTP request to 'https://secure.xxx.com/MyService.svc' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:06:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.RequestClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnRequest(TRequestChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

 Exception rethrown at [0]: 
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
    at MyWebService.IService.WaitForUpdate()
    at WebUpdater.ThreadStart(Object[] args)
```

On each retries, I'll get the same error. Only sometimes (rarely), it went ok.

Note, the internet is not terrible slow. It is about 2Mbps (using speedtest.net to test)

Any idea why?

---

### UPDATE

I tried to disable the WiFi on the working client, it does disconnected right away with the following error:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://secure.xxx.com/MyService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.RequestClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnRequest(TRequestChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
    at MyWebService.IService.WaitForUpdate()
    at WebUpdater.ThreadStart(Object[] args)
```

Comment: `even though WCF has returned a value.` How do you know?

Comment: I've put a temporarily log. I've updated the code.

Comment: What happens if you put the log *after* the serialization? So the last line is only `return localByteArray;`

Comment: Good point... let me try that...

Comment: The `SerializeBytes` went OK. The log is there. Is there a WCF send timeout (ie. timeout to send a reply back to client)?

Comment: Then I guess the next step is looking at your host's logfiles. Where do you host your service?

Comment: I hosted in Microsoft Azure. Is there a WCF send timeout (ie. timeout to send a reply back to client)?

Comment: Another idea... could it be your "slow" line is actually losing the connection? What happens if you pull the network cable on your "fast" line while waiting? Does it exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: @nvoigt, I just tried that (by disabling the wifi). I got `System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException`. I have updated the question